# If $f \in L^{1}(\Omega)$, $g \in L^{2}(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then can $f.g$ be in $L^1{\Omega}$?.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have come up with an argument which is as follows. Please correct me if it makes no sense.

Consider $\int_{\Omega}|f.g|dm$. Then if $|f|\in L^1$ then $\sqrt{|f|}\in L^2$. Hence we have $\int_{\Omega}|f.g|dm\leq||\sqrt{|f|}||_{2}||g||_{2}$. But $\sqrt{|f|}\in L^2$ implies $|f|\in L^1$ and hence we have the result.

Also can I conclude that $\int_{\Omega}|f|^2\leq(\int_{\Omega}|f|)^2$?.

Answer (score 0):

Your application of Holder's inequality is incorrect. We have either $\int|fg|\leq\|f\|_2\|g\|_2$ or $\int|\sqrt{|f|}g|\leq\|\sqrt{|f|}\|_2\|g\|_2$, but not what you have written. For a counterexample, consider $\Omega=(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and let $f(x)=x^{-2/3}$, $g(x)=x^{-1/3}$. Then $f\in L^1,g\in L^2$ but $fg\notin L^1$.

Certainly, $fg$ *can* be in $L^1$, depending on your particular $f$, $g$ and $\Omega$, but I'm assuming you meant to ask does this *imply* $fg\in L^1$, which as I have just discussed is false.

As an aside, if $m(\Omega)=1$ then the reverse of your last inequality is actually true, namely $\int_\Omega|f|^2\geq(\int_\Omega|f|)^2$. This is a special case of Jensen's inequality, but can be proved easily by noticing $\int_\Omega\big|f-\int_\Omega|f|\big|^2\geq0$.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Can you please let me know of the condition depending on my particular choice of f,g  (other than f in L^1 and g in L^{\infty})under which f.g is in L^2?.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Can you please let me know of the condition depending on my particular choice of f,g (other than f in L^1 and g in L^{\infty})under which f.g is in L^1?.